# Firefox printing pdf in new Tab not working

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, printing

I have a page with a button that opens another page with pdf in a new tab. I have also written the code to print the pdf of the new window in jquery. The code is working fine in chrome. But in firefox, while showing print dialog there is no content on the page. the pdf is only loading after the print window is closed. So it is printing a blank page

Default.aspx

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
<script>
        $('#Button1').click(function () {
            openmulWindow();
        });
        function openmulWindow() {
            var w = window.open('Print.aspx', '_newtab');
            debugger;
            var chrome = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') > -1;
            var firefox = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') > -1;
            if (chrome) {
                w.focus();
                w.print();
            }
            else if (firefox) {
                w.focus();
                w.print();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Print.aspx.cs

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string pdfFilePath = "sample1.pdf";
        string fullpath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~");
        byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullpath + pdfFilePath);

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", bytes.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

In Google Chrome, it is working fine.

ps: the pdf file is in byte[] format